# What exactly are "floaters"?

Tags: eyes

i was reading [this artical](http://www.cnet.com/au/news/detached-retina-linked-to-overtexting-in-the-dark/) after hearing about it on the news, while reading i saw the term "floaters" which made me remember of a recent Family Guy Episode in which there is a joke about them in Peter's vision.

I am wondering, what exactly are they? what is their technical term? and is it possible to remove them permanently (apart from the obvious gouging out your eyes).

Comment: When I move my eyeballs around, I see some very faint dark curvy lines(resembling blood vessels) move about with my eyeballs. Those are floaters. I'm not sure if everyone can see them.

Comment: Every question regarding floaters that you have asked is answered on the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floater